# wget: how to crawl urls with shop(#) character

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I found that # character in URL makes wget behaving differently from my expectation. Essentially url string up to # will be kept and the substring from # will be discarded. I guess that's because # is in-page navigation link? But obviously certain sites seems to be using it as "?" (beginning of url parameters). Any solution to work this around with wget? I tried curl but no luck.

Comment: Can you supply an example link where a # is not used as an anchor/bookmark? More explicit; where you get a different result if you use wget instead of your everyday browser?

Comment: Browsers are fine since they don't cut any string and pass everything as is. I am a bit reluctant to specify the example but let me see if I can find some other example.

Comment: Precisely. # is a reserved character for defining an anchor in the displayed html. This tells the browser where to put the scroll bar. It does make sense that wget couldn't care less.

Comment: I just looked at incoming requests on my webpage. If i request something including a #, the # and any trailing characters are cut off from the request. This is the same behavior you see in wget. Any page using # in a URL will never get a request that matches this URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, but I am presuming that you are using the hashtag (#) for ajax. If that is the case, using wget is pointless because it will not be able to execute the JavaScript. So if any content that is normally been generated with JavaScript will be missing.

If you want to download the contents of a webpage, with the JavaScript executed, then you need what is called a 'headless browser'. Check these out:

[htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

[phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/)

[zombiejs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)